# Apple security patch releases

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Apple recently released iOS 15.3 which patches serious security issues. I'm curious to know if this will require the app to be updated or an update would help in any way? I couldn't find info on developer.apple.com so asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm curious to know if this will require the app to be updated or an update would help in any way?

Generally, no, you shouldn't have to update your app when Apple releases a minor update. Historically, Apple has gone to great lengths to avoid breaking application code without first at least warning developers well in advance.

To be certain, though, you should routinely test your app and confirm that it runs correctly under the latest update.